# How to text file content to a tableview in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am trying to populate text file content to a table view in javafx. Below is my code:

```
public static void loadFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  ObservableList<Song> songs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();  
  File file = new File("songDATA.txt");
  FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
  String line;  
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] song = line.split("//");
    songs.add(new Song(song[0], song[1], song[2], Double.parseDouble(song[3]), 
        Integer.parseInt(song[4])));

  }
  reader.close();
}
```

But i am being given an exception error message:

> Executing
>   C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MusicLibrary\dist\r‌un1361663306\MusicLi‌​brary.jar
>   using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\jre/bin/java Oct 13,
>   2016 8:47:31 PM
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.SelectBinding$SelectBindingHelper
>   getObservableValue WARNING: Exception while evaluating select-binding
>   [width] Oct 13, 2016 8:47:31 PM
>   com.sun.javafx.binding.SelectBinding$SelectBindingHelper
>   getObservableValue WARNING: Exception while evaluating select-binding
>   [height] Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:‌​1774) at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(F‌XMLLoader.java:1657)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingE‌vent(CompositeEventH‌​andler.java:86)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEve‌nt(EventHandlerManag‌​er.java:238)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEve‌nt(EventHandlerManag‌​er.java:191)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Basi‌cEventDispatcher.jav‌​a:58)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Ev‌​entDispatchChainImpl‌​.java:114)
>   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:‌​74)
>   at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49) at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198) at
>   javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462) at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuIte‌​mContainer.doSelect(‌​ContextMenuContent.j‌​ava:1405)
>   at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuIte‌mContainer.lambda$cr‌​eateChildren$343(Con‌​textMenuContent.java‌​:1358)

Comment: and this is my text file                                                                             **J. Cole//Lost Ones//Hip Hop//24.66//3000Erykah Badu//Time's a wasting//Neo-Soul//24.66//4000Common//Book of Life//Hip Hop//24.66//2000CommonGround//dasdsad//asdsadsad//24.66//3000hoop//hoola//me//44545.0//45566**

Comment: post stacktrace

Comment: This error trace does nothing with the code you posted, so please post your whole code, otherwise it is impossible to tell what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

This error trace does nothing with the code you posted, but anyways your input file is even wrong.

You have unexpected characters in your file. Both in the fourth line "300‌​0" and in the fifth line "44‌​545.0" contains:

- one [ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER (U+200C)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm)
- one [ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm)

You can check this in [ideone](http://ideone.com/SiNc2s):

```
String str1 = "300‌​0";
String str2 = "44‌​545.0";

str1.chars().forEach(c -> System.out.println((char)c + " " + (int) ((char)c)));
System.out.println("");
System.out.println("--------------------");
str2.chars().forEach(c -> System.out.println((char)c + " " + (int) ((char)c)));
```

*Outputs (first column is the character second is the character code):*

```
3 51
0 48
0 48
‌ 8204
​ 8203
0 48
--------------------
4 52
4 52
‌ 8204
​ 8203
5 53
4 52
5 53
. 46
0 48
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys but it seem not be working, is the above loadFile function code correct though?

Comment: Please update the question with the exception trace.

Comment: Hi guys, below the exception trace